# Semantics of OMG IDL attributes

Tags: corba, idl

I'm working on the verification of an interface formalised in the OMG's IDL, and am having problems finding a definitive answer on the semantics of getting an attribute value. In an interface, I have an entry...

```
interface MyInterface {
  readonly attribute SomeType someName;
};
```

I need to know if it is acceptable for `someObj.someName != someObj.someName` to be true (where `someObj` is an instance of an object implementing `MyInterface`).

All I can find in OMG documentation in regards to attributes is...

> (5.14) An attribute definition is logically equivalent to declaring a
>   pair of accessor functions; one to retrieve the value of the attribute
>   and one to set the value of the attribute.
>
> ...
>
> The optional readonly keyword indicates that there is only a single
>   accessor function—the retrieve value function.

Ergo, I'm forced to conclude that IDL attributes need not be backed by a data member, and are free to return basically any value the interface deems appropriate. Can anyone with more experience in IDL confirm that this is indeed the case?

Comment: I don't understand why "someObj.someName != someObj.someName" can be false. if u compare the same object it will be always true. PS: Are you using Java right?

Comment: No, this is not a programming language. It's IDL, a language for describing interfaces. My question is about the semantics of implementations of IDL interfaces; i.e. what is a valid implementation.

Comment: I thik it was about OMG CORBA IDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable for `someObj.someName != someObj.someName` to be true, oddly as it may seem.

The reason (as others alluded to) is because attributes map to real RPC functions. In the case of `readonly` attributes they just map to a setter, and for non-readonly attributes there's a setter and a getter implicitly created for you when the IDL gets compiled. But the important thing to know is that **an IDL attribute has a dynamic, server-dictated, RPC-driven value**.

IDL specifies a contract for distributed interactions which can be made at runtime between independent, decoupled entities. Almost every interaction with an IDL-based type will lead to an RPC call and any return value will be dependent on what the server decides to return.

If the attribute is, say, `currentTime` then you'll perhaps get the server's current clock time with each retrieval of the value. In this case, `someObj.currentTime != someObj.currentTime` will very likely always be true (assuming the time granularity used is smaller than the combined roundtrip time for two RPC calls).

If the attribute is instead `currentBankBalance` then you can still have `someObj.currentBankBalance != someObj.currentBankBalance` be true, because there may be other clients running elsewhere who are constantly modifying the attribute via the setter function, so you're dealing with a race condition too.

All that being said, if you take a very formal look at the IDL spec, it contains no language that actually requires that the setting/accessing of an attribute should result in an RPC call to the server. It could be served by the client-side ORB. In fact, that's something which some ORB vendors took advantage of back in the CORBA heyday. I used to work on the [Orbix ORB](http://www.progress.com/en/orbix/), and we had a feature called [Smart Proxies](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/gen3/33/html/orbix33cxx_pguide/Sproxy.html) - something which would allow an application developer to overload the ORB-provided default client proxies (which would always forward all attribute calls to the server hosting the target object) with custom functionality (say, to cache the attribute values and return a local copy without incurring network or server overhead).

In summary, you need to be very clear and precise about what you are trying to verify formally. Given the dynamic and non-deterministic nature of the values they can return (and the fact that client ORBs might behave differently from each other and still remain compliant to the CORBA spec) **you can only reliably expect IDL attributes to map to getters and setters that can be used to retrieve or set a value**. There is simply no predictability surrounding the actual values returned.

Answer (score 2):

As we know, IDL *interface* always will be represented by a remote object. An *attribute* is no more then a syntatic sugar for *getAttributeName()* and *setAttributeName()*. Personally, i don't like to use *attribute* because it is hardly to understand than a simply get/set method.

CORBA also has valuetypes, object by value structure - better explaned [here](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/more-details-on-idl.html). They are very usefull because, different from struct, allow us inherit from other *valuetypes*, *abstract interface* or *abstract valuetype*. Usualy, when i'm modeling objects with alot of 
 get/set methods i prefer to use valuetypes instead of *interfaces*.

Going back to your question, the best way to understand 'attribute' is looking for C#. [IIOP.NET](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/) maps 'attribute' to [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). A property simulates a public member but they are a get/set method.

Answering your question, i can't know if `someObj.someName != someObj.someName` will return true or false without see the someObj implementation. I will add two examples to give an ideia about what we can see.

Example 1) This implementation will always return false for the expression above:

```
private static i;

public string getSomeName() {
  return "myName"   i;
}
```

Example 2) This implementation bellow can return true or false, depending of concurrency or 'race condition' between clients.

```
public string getSomeName() {
  return this.someName;
}

public setSomeName(string name) {
  this.someName = name;
}
```

First client can try to access `someObj.someName() != someObj.someName()`. A second client could call setSomeName() before de second call from the first client.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, attribute does not need to be backed by any data member on the server, although some language mapping might impose such convention.

So in general case it could happen that someObj.someName != someObj.someName. For instance attribute might be last access time.

Comment: and one more thing, accessing attribute on the client implies going over the network to fetch its value. So even if attribute is backed with data member, its value may change between 2 gets in the if above (some other user of object might set it to another value between first and second get)

Comment: That was i tried to say. Attribute is a method, so the server can do anything.

Comment: Do we have an authoritative source for this? Also, IDL isn't limited to CORBA or remote object protocols. Several standards have their interfaces specified in IDL, but are all for "normal" in process object models. Though I guess the use of it for remote objects does mean the standard is less likely to require attributes be consistent!

Comment: As Makah explains, it is a direct consequence of (5.14) An attribute definition is logically equivalent to declaring a pair of accessor functions; one to retrieve the value of the attribute and one to set the value of the attribute. CORBA IDL does not have (formal) semantics out of the CORBA model as far as I know. If you use CORBA IDL for something else, you need to specify what it means there.